# Why $f$ is of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis

Asume that $(x_n)$ is a sequence of positive numbers such  that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n <\infty$.  We define a functon $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ in the following way:

$f(x)=x_n $ if $x=\frac{1}{n}$, $n \in \mathbb N$;

$f(x)=0$ for $x\in [0,1]\setminus \{\frac{1}{k}: k\in \mathbb N \}$.

How to prove that $f$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: because the variation is twice the infinite sum of $x_n$'s.

Comment: Do you know the definition of bounded variation? Have you tried applying it to this function? What happened when you did?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't think that it follows immediately by definition of variation. In definition is a supremum of finite sums, here we have infinite sums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any finite partition
$$P:\qquad 0=x_0<x_1<x_2<\ldots< x_{N-1}<x_N=1\ ,$$ put $n_1:=\lfloor{1\over x_1}\rfloor$ and 
insert all points ${1\over n}$ $\>(2\leq n\leq n_1)$ to obtain a slightly finer partition $$P':\qquad 0=y_0<y_1<y_2<\ldots< y_{M-1}<y_M=1\ .$$ One then has
$$\sum_{k=1}^N|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|\leq \sum_{k=1}^M|f(y_k)-f(y_{k-1})|\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^{n_1}x_n\leq 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n=:C\ .$$
Since this is true for any finite partition $P$ of $[0,1]$ the function $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any partition $0=y_0<y_1<...<y_m=1$ of $[0,1]$ we have:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} |f(y_i) - f(y_{i-1})| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{m} x_{\sigma(i)} + \sum_{i=2}^{m} x_{\sigma(i-1)} ,$$
where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$.
As the series $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i$ converges absolutely (hence unconditionally), each of the above sums are bounded (bound does not depend on partition).